# Execute Jython script using java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jython

Am trying to execute a complete Jython project using java eclipse 3.4.. I have configured Jython environment in my eclipse..I went through certain tutorials which described about Building a factory.. But i guess that method can be used to execute applications that are specific to a particular Jython module.. What I exactly need is::

To run the entire Jython project as a java application, by using the .class file created in the Jython project..

Not sure if this is feasible.. Suggestions please..

Answer (score 2):

One Java class with an embedded PythonInterpreter is capable of kicking off an entire Jython application.  May need to play around with setting the appropriate python.home and library paths, look in the PyServletInitializer and PyFilter for examples of how this is done.

Another option is use PyDev and just run a Jython script to start the application, bypassing the need for a Java application all together.